# Could Haise Sasaki regain his memories if he accepted his ghoul side?

Tags: tokyo-ghoul

Haise Sasaki is an amnesiac and remembers nothing of his true identity, but if he accepted his ghoul side, wouldn't he regain his memories, his original identity, and his full power? That would make sense, considering that his Rize was his original personality, which appeared to him during a battle with the S ranked ghoul Orochi, and asking him to accept his true identity as a ghoul. If you know his true identity, good for you don't spoil it for those who don't know. They probably don't want spoilers. If you don't know who he is, read the manga or watch the anime. Tokyo ghoul season 3 just came out. you'll find out in Tokyo ghoul Re:

Comment: The answer to this question would most probably be opinion based.

Answer (score 1):

I waited for someone else to answer this question and no one did. As I said earlier, the answer will be opinion based as there is no evidence we could provide from the anime/manga. However, I will try to answer it best to my knowledge (my opinion of course)

---

Haise Sasaki, the protagonist of *Tokyo Ghoul:re*, is a First Class Ghoul Investigator, the mentor of the Quinx Squad and a member of Team Mado. You can predict (from Season 3's first episode or if you've read the manga) that he is self-contained, good-natured individual. As a Ghoul Investigator, he comes off as trustworthy, loyal and devoted. While he portrays a serious demeanour toward his work, Haise is also merciful to some extent, as he believes that an Investigator should not annihilate ghouls unnecessarily.

> Haise Sasaki is an amnesiac and remembers nothing of his true identity

Just for your information that if you think Haise doesn't remember that he was a ghoul before, you are wrong! He experiences memory loss yet he is aware of his ghoul side to some extent.

But, unlike Kaneki who accepted his ghoul side, Haise **rejects** it and seem to be disgusted by his ghoul side as when it tried to convince him to accept it, he ignored it and thought of his mentors (Akira and Arima) to give him courage.

Thus *if* he accepts his true identity (which seems to be very unexpected for now) and meets up with his former ghoul friends, he *might* regain his memories and full power.

Comment: Yeah, I know he's aware of his ghoul side, but he doesn't accept it. However, Haise's personality comes across as the kind of person who would do anything to save his friends, which, if you think back, was Kaneki's downfall. So I believe he would possibly accept his ghoul side if he were in a bad enough situation, and he thought it would mean enough power to protect those he cares about.

Comment: I agree, but your question is if he would regain his memories due to that (which leads to opinion based answer)

Comment: yeah, because originally, Rize would take over when Kaneki accepted her powers for short periods of time, and she would appear to him every time she felt weakness in his heart and his resolve wearing thin, and she thought she could convince him to accept her. His original identity appeared to Haise in the same manner, meaning if he gave in and accepted his ghoul side, his original identity would take over, and most probably he would regain the memories that made that identity who he was along with it. By restoring these and his main identity, it would allow him to use his power to its fullest.